# C# webClient.DownloadFile exception issues

Tags: c#

Currently I have a very simple code that downloads a file from a server, however i keep running into the following exceptions:

The remote server returned an error: (500)
Unable to connect to the remote server

There is nothing wrong with the webserver it has to do with my service and i guess it times out, how can i handle these more robustly?  I have my code shown below, it's really simple.

```
            try
        {
            string[] splitCrawlerid = StaticStringClass.crawlerID.Split('t');
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            if (Directory.Exists("C:\\ImageDepot\\" + splitCrawlerid[2]))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\ImageDepot\\" + splitCrawlerid[2]);

            }
            webClient.DownloadFile(privateHTML, @"C:\ImageDepot\" + splitCrawlerid[2] + "\\" + "AT" + carID + ".jpeg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
//not sure how to really handle these two exceptions reliably
}
```

The ideal situation for me would be to attempt to download the file again.

Comment: HTTP Error Code 500 is an Internal Server Error.

Comment: okay, sorry if i don't understand, i'm sure that the problem resides on my box, the issue is i know if i just retry it, eventually it will connect and i dont want to make some bland retry thing that will get stuck in a loop

Comment: When you say "your box", do you mean your computer or the web server?

Comment: my computer, sorry for any confusion

Comment: What URL are you using to download the file?

Comment: the URL is fine, and like i said if i just repeat it, it will eventually happen i just dont want to do a while catch like answered below, even though thats the way i'm about to do it

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a [user-agent header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).  The [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) doesn't send that be default and MSDN warns that some web servers will return a 500 error if user-agent isn't set.

> A WebClient instance does not send optional HTTP headers by default.
>   If your request requires an optional header, you must add the header
>   to the Headers collection. For example, to retain queries in the
>   response, you must add a user-agent header. Also, servers may return
>   500 (Internal Server Error) if the user agent header is missing.

See the example on the MSDN page for how to add the header.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the whole thing in a for loop that goes 0..3, and the line after `webClient.DownloadFile(...)` could be a `break;`.  That way if there's an exception, the `break` gets skipped and the app tries again.  But that seems to be more of a band-aid to me; I'd spend more time figuring out exactly why things are going wrong.

If you want to remove all the "try while blah else until rethrow whatever" code from the business logic of your app, you could define an extension method like

```
public static T TryNTimes<T>(this Func<T> func, int n) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            return func();
        } catch {
            if (++i == n) throw;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
Func<File> downloader = () => client.DownloadFile(...);
var file = downloader.TryNTimes(5);
```

Comment: i was actually going to do something like public static int countdown = 0; while { countdown < 5} catch repeat, but i think thats probably bad practice to the X power.

Comment: Does the TryNTimes help in that respect?  (Actually I guess for WebClient.DownloadFile you'll need an Action instead of a Func<T> since DownloadFile returns void).